# Accessing C# property name or attributes

Tags: c#, properties

I would like to automatically generate SQL statements from a class instance. The method should look like Update(object[] Properties, object PrimaryKeyProperty). The method is part of an instance (class, base method - generic for any child). Array of properties is an array of class properties, that will be used in *update* statement. Property names are equal to table field names.

The problem is that I can't get property names.

Is there any option to get a property name inside class instance?
sample:

```
public class MyClass {
public int iMyProperty { get; set; }
public string cMyProperty2 { get; set; }
{

main() {
 MyClass _main = new MyClass();

_main.iMyProperty.*PropertyName* // should return string "iMyProperty"

{
```

I am aware of PropertyInfo, but I don't know hot to get the ID of a property from GetProperties() array.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 28):

[Just wrote an implementation of this](http://code.google.com/p/gim-projects/source/browse/presentations/CantDanceTheLambda/src/MemberNameParser.cs) for a presentation on lambdas for our usergroup last Tuesday.

- You can do

  MembersOf<Animal>.GetName(x => x.Status)
- Or

  var a = new Animal()
     a.MemberName(x => x.Status)

the code:

```
public static class MembersOf<T> {
    public static string GetName<R>(Expression<Func<T,R>> expr) {
        var node = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(null, node)) 
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Expression must be of member access");
        return node.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

- [Link to the presentation and code samples](http://gim-projects.googlecode.com/files/CantDanceTheLambda.zip).
- Also in SVN (more likely to be updated): http://gim-projects.googlecode.com/svn/presentations/CantDanceTheLambda

Comment: Hi George, your solution does not work for nested Lambda's like MembersOf<Animal>.GetName(x => x.Gender.Text) should give "Gender.Text", not just "Text".

Comment: @Stef, that is correct. x.Gender.Text is not a member accessor. Check the implementation though, it should be relatively easy to make it detect a whole syntax tree and recurse repeatedly

Comment: the answer from LukeH at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049825/given-a-member-access-lambda-expression-convert-it-to-a-specific-string-represen is exactly what I need.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Why don't you replace `MembersOf<T>.GetName<R>(Expression<Func<T,R>> expr)` with **`MembersOf.GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T,Object>> expr)`**, it's easier and you don't need a specific R type (even it's inferred at compilation).

Comment: @YvesM. what advantage would that hold?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Types T and R are separated: **MembersOf<T>** and **GetName<R>** instead of GetName<T,R>. This has been done only to have type R isolated so **R can be inferred**. The problem is when I need to use MembersOf in another function I will have to specify T and R without being able to separate them. For example: `public string MyFunction<T,R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expr){return new MembersOf<T>().GetName<R>()}`. T and R are no longer separated and R cannot be inferred when using MyFunction<T,R>. But if you replace R with Object, you don't have to do tricks to facilitate inferrance

Comment: @GeorgeMauer and it will be semantically more accurate. Nobody cares about type R. We only need the expression to returns something.. anything.. Object!

Comment: Good point on the type inference, I'm less inclined to agree to the latter though. `<T,R>` with no constraints means "any T and any R", whereas `<T, Object>` could potentially mean "any T and a downcast/boxed object". Your point might be carried better by a `<T, dynamic>` signature. Either way, these are all very minor considerations - I probably wouldn't even mention them in a code review.

Answer (score 10):

I found a perfect solution in [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection)

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
   return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

And then for the usage :

```
var propertyName = GetPropertyName(
() => myObject.AProperty); // returns "AProperty"
```

Works like a charm

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
Type t = someInstance.getType();

foreach (MemberInfo mi in t.GetMembers())
{
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(mi.Name);
    }
}
```

to get all the property names for `instance`'s type.

Comment: He doesn't want all property names, just specific ones

Comment: Not sure that merits a downvote. The question says, "is there any option to get property name inside class instance?" I've shown a loop which goes through printing *all* the property names in a class instance, but he can all get the ones he wants to update into an array which he passes to the Update procedure. I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name (I assume that's what you meant by ID) of a property using PropertyInfo.Name.  Just loop through the PropertyInfo[] returned from typeof(className).GetProperties()

```
foreach (PropertyInfo info in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties())
{
    string name = info.Name;
    // use name here
}
```

Comment: I wish I could give you +10 for this :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have an explicit handle to the specific property you want, you know the name - can you just type it?

Comment: I think he wants the code to work for derived classes as well, so he needs to use reflection.

Comment: The main idea is not to duplicate names. So when a class (with attributes) is written I get an automatic table generation, CRUD statements and *Intellisense*.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say (from the first sample, method update of a class `MyClass`):

```
public class MyClass {

public int iMyStatusProperty { get; set; }
public int iMyKey { get; set; }

public int UpdateStatusProperty(int iValue){
this.iMyStatusProperty = iValue;
return _Update( new[iMyStatusProperty ], iMyKey); // this should generate SQL: "UPDATE MyClass set iMyStatusProperty = {iMyStatusProperty} where iMyKey = {iMyKey}"
}
```

`{iMyStatusProperty}` and `{iMyKey}` are property values of a class instance.

So, the problem is how to get property name (*reflection*) from a property without using names of properties as strings (to avoid field name typos).

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this will get you what you're looking for, this will fetch all properties with [Column] attribute inside your class:
In the datacontext I have:

```
 public ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> ColumnNames<TEntity>( )
    {
        return this.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel(typeof(DataContext)).GetMetaType(typeof(TEntity)).DataMembers;
    }
```

Fetching the table column-names that are properties inside the class:

```
       MyDataContext db = GetDataContext(); 
       var allColumnPropertyNames =   db.ColumnNames<Animal>().Where(n => n.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() != null).Select(n => n.Name);
```