# Given a Member Access lambda expression, convert it to a specific string representation with full access path

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Given an

```
Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

(e.g. x => x.Prop1.SubProp), I want to create a string "Prop1.SubProp" for as deep as necessary.

In the case of a single access (e.g. x => x.Prop1), I can easily do this with:

```
MemberExpression body = (expression.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert) ? (MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expression.Body).Operand : (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
return body.Member.Name;
```

However, if there is deeper nesting, e.g. x => x.Prop1.SubProp1, this only gets the most deeply nested name, e.g. "SubProp1" instead of "Prop1.SubProp1"

Is there anyway to access the full property path of a lambda expression?

Comment: Take a look at MemberExpression.Expression.  You can probably use that to recursively walk the expression tree as long as they are all MemberExpression instances.

Comment: I had a hard time choosing an "accepted answer" both were good.  Anybody viewing this question, I recommend looking at the answers from both LukeH and Dan Tao.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the property, as a string, from an Expression<Func<TModel,TProperty>>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789504/get-the-property-as-a-string-from-an-expressionfunctmodel-tproperty)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
public string GetPath<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expr)
{
    var stack = new Stack<string>();

    MemberExpression me;
    switch (expr.Body.NodeType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.Convert:
        case ExpressionType.ConvertChecked:
            var ue = expr.Body as UnaryExpression;
            me = ((ue != null) ? ue.Operand : null) as MemberExpression;
            break;
        default:
            me = expr.Body as MemberExpression;
            break;
    }

    while (me != null)
    {
        stack.Push(me.Member.Name);
        me = me.Expression as MemberExpression;
    }

    return string.Join(".", stack.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: +1: Great minds think alike! One little thing: don't you think this really ought to be defined `GetPath<T, TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> expr)`? Otherwise you're nearly always going to run into that `Convert`/`ConvertChecked` scenario -- simply because the argument is cast unnecessarily. (Or am I missing something?)

Comment: @Dan: Yep, I agree. In fact, before my edits I had the signature as `GetPath<T,U>(Expression<Func<T,U>> expr)`. I changed it to match the expression shown in the question. I'll leave it as-is, and I suppose the OP can choose which signature they prefer - the code in the method body stays the same either way.

Comment: Any idea how to modify this to work with an expression that contains index (ie square bracket) operator(s)?

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789504/get-the-property-as-a-string-from-an-expressionfunctmodel-tproperty/2789606#2789606).

Pretty much the same as what LukeH posted, with one additional feature:

If you have a type, say, `MyClass`, with a property `MyProperty` of type `int`, you could write this:

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> e = x => x.MyProperty;
```

Here the expression `e.Body` is *not* a `MemberExpression` so the simple `while (me != null) me = me.Expression as MemberExpression` won't work.

The solution is to check additionally if it's a `UnaryExpression` with `NodeType == Convert` or `ConvertChecked`.

There may be other scenarios to account for; but for simple chains of property expressions, this approach works pretty well.

Comment: I was just editing my answer to take account of `Convert`/`ConvertChecked` when you edited yours.

Comment: @LukeH: What can I say? Clearly you know what you're doing ;)

Comment: Do you know of a clean way to preserve array access as an indexing expression rather than a MemberCallExpression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a project I have created to convert lambda to javascript: [lambda2js](https://github.com/gearz-lab/lambda2js)

When using only properties and indexers, the result should be exactly what you need.

Example 1: Single property path

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr = x => x.Phone;
var js = expr.CompileToJavascript();
// returns: Phone
```

Example 2: Path containing indexer of a string dictionary

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr = x => x.PhonesByName["Miguel"];
var js = expr.CompileToJavascript();
// returns: PhonesByName["Miguel"]
```

Example 3: Complex path containing indexers and multiple levels

```
Expression<Func<MyClass, object>> expr = x => x.SomeProp["Miguel"].Subprop[0].A.B;
var js = expr.CompileToJavascript();
// returns: SomeProp["Miguel"].Subprop[0].A.B
```