# Changing the properties of an object in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, class, object, dynamic, foreach

my class

```
class person
{
    public string name;
    public string age;
    public string height;
    public string weight;
}
```

This is what I want to do...

```
person john = new person();
int i=0;

List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "John", "22", "174cms" ,"60kgs"};  
foreach(property in john)
{
    property = myList[i].toString();
    i++;
}
```

How do I do this? Or can I actually do this?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, not easily anyway. This is normally done with an object initialiser which saves the hassle of writing out the variable name many times.

```
person john = new person
{
    name = "John",
    age = "22",
    height = "174cms",
    weight = "60kgs"
};
```

You could do something like this with [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but you would be losing type safety as you would be assigning a value to the `i`th index and I'm not so sure what the order of the properties come out as when you extract them. Reflection is a pretty advanced (and potentially dangerous) part of C# and you should probably stay away from it until you really need it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen these posts?

[How to get the list of properties of a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737151/how-to-get-the-list-of-properties-of-class)

[Get string name of property using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection)

I hope this helps you. May be instead of a list you can use a datatable and name each column to the name of each property in your class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this with Reflection, something like

`john.GetType().GetProperties();`

But - don't do it! Consider to change your implementation to make it in better way.
For example - if you should use list with person details in this way, and myList properties always came in same order - update john specific properties, like:

```
john.name = myList[0];
..
```

But I'd suggest to re-design your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) for retrieving the properties

```
PropertyInfo[] info = john.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Unfortunately, the manual says

> **Remarks**
>   The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that order varies.

So you must still match the `info` with `myList` manually.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of the long way around to do it that way.  If you know your list is always going to be in that format just do something like.

```
var john = new person 
{
    name = myList[0],
    age = myList[1],
    height = myList[2],
    weight = myList[3]
}
```