# How is generic TKey interpreted in C# when using lambda notation?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, polymorphism, expression

I want to use some `System.Linq` extension methods in a base class whereas derived classes should be able to provide some expressions by overriding specific methods.

Current base class code:

```
lQuery.OrderBy(s => s.ID) <-- works, *1
```

I want to replace `s => s.ID` by a method call that can be overridden:

```
... Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> GetOrderByKey<TSource, TKey>()
{
  ...
}
```

But when I override the method like

```
override Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>> GetOrderByKey<TSource, TKey>()
{
    return s => s.ID; <-- compiler error, *2
}
```

the compiler outputs the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'TKey'

1. Why is the generic parameter `TKey` magically deduced (and to what?) in line 1 but in line 2 it is deduced to the actual type of the ID property?
2. How to resolve the compiler error?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I struggle to find the right explanation of the issue. Let's break it down to the following simple lines:

```
  var lQuery = from s in ... select s;

  lQuery = lQuery.OrderBy(s => s.ID); // *3
```

How exactly is that `OrderBy` call interpreted by the compiler as it results in an `ORDER BY ID ASC` instead of `ORDER BY %Value of ID% ASC`? The compiler seems to somehow decide to deduce `s.ID` to `property name "ID"` instead of taking the  actual property data type and thus the int value.

**Edit2**

Ok, another example for +D Stanley

This works:

```
void SetOrder<TKey>(IQueryable<%type of s%> aQuery, Expression<Func<%type of s%, TKey>> aKeySelector)
{
    aQuery.OrderBy(aKeySelector);
}

...

SetOrder(aQuery, s => s.ID); // <-- works
```

But this not (the compile error is display as mentioned before)

```
protected void SetOrder<TKey>(IQueryable<%type of s%> aQuery)
{
    Expression<Func<%type of s%, TKey>> lKeySelector = s => s.ID; // <-- deduced to int

    aQuery.OrderBy(lKeySelector);
}
```

Comment: Has to be a `Func<T>` for the `OrderBy`, if I remember correctly. You could remove the `Expression` bit, I think..

Comment: By the time you're overriding your GetOrderByKey() method, you ought to know what type `TKey` is, so it should be an explicit parameter on your class override: `class FooRepo : FooBase<Foo, int>`. That means the generic parameters for TKey and TSource should be on the class itself, not on this method.

Comment: Can you show some more context around *1? There's not enough information to see why it works there.

Comment: Can you the class definitions ? I suspect you may be re-using `TKey` when it's already defined at the class level.

Comment: TSource must implement IComparable interface. Please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.icomparable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: +Maciej Los Can you please fix the link? This might be the solution but i cannot open it.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, done!

Comment: +Maciej Los k, thx. Unfortunately implementing that interface wont work imho. See my edit for a better example of the issue, +D Stanley nope TKey is mysteriously introduced by System.Linq.IQueryable, +Erik see the additional example added

Comment: Your question of "How does `OrderBy` work" is pretty straightforward, but I doubt it will help you fix your issue.  You need to post the class definition and more context to understand what the problem is.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy There's no "magic" with `TKey` in `IQueryable` - it's just a generic parameter.

Comment: +D Stanley Please see Edit2, i don't know how to describe it in another way.

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy, after all those edits... seems you want to define custom selector to provide sort on this field (property). Am i right?

Comment: +Maciej Los yes partially right, i simply want the derived class to provide a custom selector for the base class _but_ this selector should not be specific to a concrete type. That's why i struggle to make TKey "dynamic".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have written my question in a way that no one understands my intentions. My goal was to avoid writing the same `.OrderBy()` / `.ThenBy()` code (*1) again and again for each field that needs to be sorted.

So i got the idea of adding a *SortKey* into the mix and when a *SortKey* matches (*2) then i call an extension method that does the appropriate calls for sorting (*3). Works like a charm.

`IQueryable` **extension method**

```
public static System.Linq.IQueryable<TRecord> Sort<TRecord, TKey>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<TRecord> aQuery, 
  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TRecord, TKey>> aSortFieldSelector, SortOrder aSortOrder, bool aIsPrimarySort)
{
  System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TRecord> lOrderedQuery = aIsPrimarySort ? null : aQuery as System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable<TRecord>;

  // *1
  if (aSortOrder == SortOrder.Descending)
  {
    if (lOrderedQuery == null)
      lOrderedQuery = aQuery.OrderByDescending(aSortFieldSelector);
    else
      lOrderedQuery = lOrderedQuery.ThenByDescending(aSortFieldSelector);
  }
  else
  {
    if (lOrderedQuery == null)
      lOrderedQuery = aQuery.OrderBy(aSortFieldSelector);
    else
      lOrderedQuery = lOrderedQuery.ThenBy(aSortFieldSelector);
  }

  if (lOrderedQuery != null)
    return lOrderedQuery.AsQueryable();
  else
    return aQuery;
}
```

**Base class**

```
public class BaseClass
{
  // public
    public void DoSomething()
    {
      System.Linq.IQueryable<TRecord> lQuery = ...
      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, SortOrder> lSorting = ...

      ...
      SortQuery(lQuery, lSorting);
      ...
    }

  // protected
    protected abstract void SortQuery(ref System.Linq.IQueryable<TRecord> aQuery, string aSortKey, SortOrder aSortOrder, bool aIsPrimarySort);

  // private
    private void SortQuery(ref System.Linq.IQueryable<TRecord> aQuery, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, SortOrder> aSorting)
    {
      bool lIsPrimarySort = true;

      foreach (string lSortKey in aSorting.Keys)
      {
        SortQuery(ref aQuery, lSortKey, aSorting[lSortKey], lIsPrimarySort);

        lIsPrimarySort = false;
      }
    }
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
  // protected
    protected override void SortQuery(ref IQueryable<CouponTableRecord> aQuery, string aSortKey, SortOrder aSortOrder, bool aIsPrimarySort)
    {
      if (aSortKey == SortKeys.ID) // *2
        aQuery = aQuery.Sort(r => r.ID, aSortOrder, aIsPrimarySort); // *3
      else
      if (aSortKey == SortKeys.Caption) 
        aQuery = aQuery.Sort(r => r.Caption, aSortOrder, aIsPrimarySort);
      else
        ...
    }

  // private
    private class SortKeys
    {
      public const string ID = "ID";
      public const string Caption = "Caption";
      ...
    }      
}
```

Regarding my question

> How exactly is that `OrderBy` call interpreted by the compiler as it
>   results in an `ORDER BY ID ASC` instead of `ORDER BY %Value of ID% ASC`?
>   The compiler seems to somehow decide to deduce `s.ID` to property name
>   `ID` instead of taking the actual property data type and thus the `int`
>   value.

I found an interesting [blog](https://handcraftsman.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/how-to-get-c-property-names-without-magic-strings/) and also a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262225/3936440) about this. Basically it is done by drilling into the expression body to get the member name:

```
Expression<Func<int>> expression = () => Sample.Foo;
MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
string name = body.Member.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

> How does `OrderBy` infer what the types of `TSource` and `TKey` are

The compiler can infer the types of `TSource` and `TKey` by looking at:

1. the type of `lQuery` - in this case, `IQueryable<{your class}>`
2. the return type of the expression, in this case, the type of the `ID` property of `{your class}`

> How to resolve the compiler error?

You're asking the *caller* to specify the type of `TKey` (via the generic parameter), but in your method you are specifying an expression of a *known type*.  You can just remove the generic argument:

```
protected void SetOrder(IQueryable<%type of s%> aQuery)
{
  Expression<Func<%type of s%, int>> lKeySelector = s => s.ID; 

  aQuery.OrderBy(lKeySelector);
}
```

But note that `OrderBy` *returns* a query - it does not *change* the original query, so what you *really* want is something like:

```
protected IQueryable<%type of s%> SetOrder(IQueryable<%type of s%> aQuery)
{
  Expression<Func<%type of s%, int>> lKeySelector = s => s.ID; 

  return aQuery.OrderBy(lKeySelector);
}
```

or *possibly*

```
protected void SetOrder(ref IQueryable<%type of s%> aQuery)
{
  Expression<Func<%type of s%, int>> lKeySelector = s => s.ID; 

  aQuery = aQuery.OrderBy(lKeySelector);
}
```

But using `ref` parameters is generally discouraged - it is preferable to *return* a new value rather than changing the original value.

Comment: Thanks for putting time into answering but i think i have written my question in a way that no one understands my intentions. I don't want to get rid of the compiler error as this is just a side effect. I'm trying to create a method that can be overridden by a derived class to provide a custom selector for the base class _but_ this selector should not be specific to a concrete type. That's why i struggle to make TKey "dynamic". I've found a solution myself already that fits my needs, see my answer.