# How to get the name of an image resource as a string

Tags: c#, image, embedded-resource

I have tried a few methods to obtain a name including investigating `PropertyItems` and the old fashioned `ToString()` method to try to obtain the name of an image resource as a string.

I have a selection of images, named, in a resources file. I have no issue getting the image to display using `resource.imageName`. I would like to try to get **`imageName`** as a string to reduce errors and typos elsewhere in my code.

using `resource.imageName.ToString()` provides me with the string `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

Comment: `bmp = Resources.imgname;` will be a compile error is there is a typo. getting them using a string variable will result in a runtime error when there is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function:

```
public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
{
    return (propertyExpression.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
}
```

And then use it in this way:

```
public class ClassName {
   public Foo { get; set; }
}
...
...
...
var inst = new ClassName();
var propertyName = GetPropertyName(() => inst.Foo);
```

It wasn't me who came up with this, I took it from other topic and ran it to see if it works but my browser crashed and I can't find the link to the original topic. I will edit my post as soon as I find it.

Edit: [I've found it!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661824/get-string-name-of-property-using-reflection/3661883#3661883) This is where I took the snippet from. Good luck.

Edit2: If you are able to get resource.imageName with ease, then just pass it to GetPropertyName function. If not, I guess my answer is incomplete

Comment: Thank you, that works! Didnt need the classname bit and replaced inst with the resources file instead

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015 you can use [nameof()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx)

```
string s = nameof(Resource1.myfile); // s = "myfile"
```

Comment: i use VS Express 2010